# what is best way to leave a groovy script prematurely (except system.exit(0))

Tags: groovy

what is best way to leave a groovy script prematurely ?

A groovy script reads a row from a given info file then makes some verification work, in case of verification fails (inconsistent data) script needs to leave the flow  prematurely . Then system will call the script again to read next row of the same info file

Code example :

```
 read a row
 try{
   //make some verification here
 }catch(Exception e){
    logger("exception on something occurred "+e,e)
    //here need to leave a groovy script prematurely
 }
```

Comment: To restart where you left off is going to be your problem...  Can't you move the loop inside whatever is calling the groovy, and just verify each line in the script?  Or maybe pass the script a BufferedReader which can be used to read the lines, but will maintain state between invocations of the script?

Comment: Thanks for comment , in my case server is doing all routine job

Comment: It your try catch isn't inside another try catch you can throw a new Exception

Answer (score 33):

Just use `System.exit(0)`.

```
try {
    // code
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger("exception on something occurred "+e,e)
    System.exit(0)
}
```

---

You could use the exit status code to indicate what line you had problems with.

A zero value would indicate that everything was OK, and a positive value would be the line number. You could then let your groovy script take the start line as an input parameter.

---

This is a naive implementation with just a silly exception if a line is empty.

```
file = new File(args[0])
startLine = args[1].toInteger()

file.withReader { reader ->
    reader.eachLine { line, count ->
        try {
            if (count >= startLine) {
                if (line.length() == 0) throw new Exception("error")
                println count + ': ' + line
            }
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            System.exit(count)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but I can't use system.exit(0) in my case , (sorry I didn't mention it in the beginning) , I looking for another solution

Comment: @Toren OK, but it would be great if you could update your question with more information. Then I am sure that you will get an answer that suits your needs.

Comment: this causes jenkins shutdown

Comment: I wonder how many *accidental* shutdowns it has caused so far.

Comment: Please @KrzysztofJabłoński, tell me where Jenkins was mentioned in the original question. I'll be waiting for a reference to it. BTW the `(except system.exit(0))` part in the headline was added after my answer was posted.

Comment: It was not. It only appeared in comments so far. That's why I added safety notice for multi-thread applications in my edit of your answer. But it was rejected. IMO it is a valid part of an answer to restrict some solutions for certain scenarios only. This answer should only apply to single thread top level applications. BTW: Jenkins is not the only software capable of executing arbitrary groovy code, .e.g. `gmaven-plugin` for maven from codehaus to mention one. Using `System.exit(exitCode)` there aborts the build with no message telling what has happened.

Comment: Just to clarify -- if you are running Groovy in Jenkins you can simple throw some exception. E.g. `throw new RuntimeException("Build failed. Stopping.");`. Can be thrown anywhere in a step "Execute system Groovy script" (also in functions). You might also want to set result before throwing: `build.setResult(Result.FAILURE)`.

Comment: Thanks for the commentary notes regarding Jenkins, saved me from a headache.

Comment: When using this in custom groovy scripts in Jira, you'll also accidentally shut down Jira - similar to the issue with Jenkins. The other top answer, using `return` appears to work in this scenario.

Answer (score 32):

I'm pretty sure you can just `return` from a script.

Comment: I've tried a simple script, but it doesn't seem to work. The script (two lines): 
`#!/usr/bin/groovy
return 1;`
After running the script, `echo $?` shows 0 instead of 1 on my ubuntu machine

Comment: Sorry, my answer was about leaving a Groovy script prematurely.  I honestly haven't tried to use the actual return value.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use return:

```
 read a row
 try{
  //make some verification here
 }catch(Exception e){
   logger("exception on something occurred "+e,e)
   //here need to leave a groovy script prematurely
   return
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use return **0**

```
 read a row
 try{
   //make some verification here
 }catch(Exception e){
    logger("exception on something occurred "+e,e)
    return 0;
 }
```