# jmeter exit code in bash script always returns 0

Tags: bash, jmeter, load-testing

Using `jmeter` in a bash script, how can I manage that it returns a non zero value if any assertion failed?

```
jmeter -n -t someFile.jmx
echo $?

# always returns 0, even if an assertion failed
```

I tried with a `Bean Shell Assertion` using the script:

```
if (ResponseCode.equals("200") == false) {
  System.exit(-1);
}
```

But this does not even return `0`, it just kills the process (I guess?)

May anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is there any log file generated from this command `jmeter -n -t someFile.jmx`?

Comment: Why you must change system exit code? it should be used on uncaught/ severe/specific exceptions

Comment: @user7294900 I am running jmeter in a pipeline and the pipeline should fail if the load tests fail. Therefore I need some data and I thought the exit code would be the easiest to handle. Any other recommendations?

Comment: @AbhijitPritam Yes there is, and I could `grep` or something, but I'd like to have a lean solution.

Comment: when it always return `0` you have to take the help of log file I think.

Comment: @RagnarLothbrok use jmeter plugin

Comment: @AbhijitPritamDutta as the documentation says (1.4.4 Non-GUI Mode (Command Line mode) -> https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html) you must use the `-l` option and specify a target log file which will be created.

Answer (score 6):

Put the following code in [JSR223 Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)

```
System.exit(1);
```

It will return error level `1` which will be displayed in Linux when executing `echo $?`

Comment: Easiest way to go. You can also use BeanShell sampler

Answer (score 1):

I used the following approach ([taken from here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)) for JMeter version 4.0 within a [`JSR223 Assertion`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with scripting language set to `groovy`.
But watch out [where you use System.exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12386951/1306012).

First with a [`JSR223 Assertion`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) we collect all sampler that have failed tests and put them into a user defined variable:

```
String expectedCode = "200";
if(!expectedCode.equals(prev.getResponseCode())){
  String currentValue = vars.get("failedTests");
  currentValue = currentValue + "Expected <response code> [" + expectedCode + "] but we got instead [" + prev.getResponseCode() + "] in sampler: '" + sampler.name + "'\n"
  vars.put("failedTests",currentValue);
}
```

Then, based on that variable, at the very end of the test we check if it contains any value. In such a case we fail the whole suite and log accordingly:

```
String testResults = vars.get("failedTests");

if(testResults.length() > 0)
{
  println testResults;
  log.info(testResults);

  println "Exit the system now with: System.exit(1)";
  System.exit(1);
} else {
  println "All test passed!";
  log.info("All test passed!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you only care about jmeter returning exit code when errors are found, you can check the .log for lines with error afterwards:

```
test $(grep -c ERROR jmeter.log) -eq 0
```

If you call `echo $?`, you can see it returns 1 if errors are found and 0, if not.

Answer (score 0):

1. I cannot reproduce your issue, are you sure your assertion really works? The code is more or less ok, however it also matters where you place it.

   ```
   #./jmeter -n -t test.jmx
   Creating summariser <summary>
   Created the tree successfully using test.jmx
   Starting the test @ Thu Jun 21 07:34:49 CEST 2018 (1529559289011)
   Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
   #echo $?
   255
   ```
2. You can use [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin) which can automatically mark build as unstable or failed in case of certain thresholds met/exceeded.
3. You can use [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper for JMeter test. It has powerful and flexible [pass/fail criteria](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) subsystem where you can define your assertions logic, if there will be failures - Taurus will return non-zero exit code to the parent shell.